# Two ways of looking at derivative at $x=0$ of $f (x)= x^{2} \sin1/x $

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

To show that derivative of $f$ at $x= 0$ exists, where $f(x)= x^{2} \sin1/x$,
 for $x\ne0$, and $f(0)=0$.

I did this by using definition of differentiability, then I found it to be $0$ so it exists but when I simply take derivative of this function I get $ -\cos1/x  + 2x\sin1/x$ which does not seem to exist at $x=0$. Why this contradiction?

Comment: The derivative exists, but is not continuous.

Comment: what is the definition of $F(0)$?

Answer (score 8):

The expression $\sin (1/x)$ is undefined in $0$, so in fact, you deal with the function
$$
F(x):=
\begin{cases}
x^2\,\sin(1/x)\quad\text{for}\quad x\neq 0 \\
0\quad\text{for}\quad x=0
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, you cannot use the formulas for multiplication and composition of functions, because it's *not* the function "$x^2\,\sin(1/x)$" at $0$. You need to compute it from the definition as you did, and $F'(0)=0$.

Note that $\lim_{x\to 0} F'(x)$ doesn't exists, but that does not contradict anything; the derivative is simply not continuous in $0$, although it is defined everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for answer , i didn't quite follow you ,

Comment: What do you mean by its not the function x^2sin1/x in zero

Comment: I think he means “*at* 0” instead of “*in* 0”.  The function is not defined by the formula $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ at zero, because that expression is meaningless at $x=0$.  So you can't use the rules of differentiation at zero; you can *only* use the definition.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for the correction, I didn't know that there is a difference between "in zero" and "at zero". Need to work on my math-english. :)